# received remote notification doesn't appear in notification center, but badge number on the app icon appears

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, apple-push-notifications

iphone app, which I made, works oddly on some devices. I've confirmed the app has registered itself to APN and received device token correctly. actually, the app put the token into the remote database. However, when I send a remote notification some devices, running iOS 5.0.1, doesn't show the remote notification in the notification center. Weird thing is that, the badge number of app icon is shown correctly when the notification is received. So, I'm guessing something goes messed up in the OS. What can I do to resolve it, or even to find a cause?
Those devices were used for development, and the same app was installed signed with development profile. Newly installed app is signed with distribution profile and I'm sure I'm using correct APN server & cert/key files, not for sandbox. Other devices, running iOS 4.3 or 5.1 beta, handles remote notification with no problems.

Comment: Have you checked the settings for your app in the notification centre - ie is it enabled?

Comment: @NickBull sure. that's the first thing I did.

Comment: Just checking the basics first! That's a strange one. What about handling the notification when the app is open and displaying or logging what is received?

Comment: all of sudden, one of those problematic devices has started showing remote notification correctly after a few hours. this makes me certain that something goes wrong with iOS or APN server =(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on IOS 6 (not tested on other OS).
The number of badge has been updated but there was no notification displayed.

The problem was the notification data were too long, I put custom data (such as the list of identifiers). Apple allows 256 bytes (ie 256 characters). That is why sometimes the notification was displayed, sometimes not (because the data I generated were too long and exceeded the limit of 256 bytes).

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a certificate problem that can result from a provisioning profile being created after enabling push for an App ID. Revoke any certificates (to be safe) and re-make the provisioning profiles with those new certificates and app IDs. Remove old certs and provisioning profiles from your Mac and re-deploy the app. It should work then.